# How to think about heuristics

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I have a game about drone delivery company.

The game consists of a rectangular map, which contains tiles that cannot be passed. I can control a certain amount of drones, each one of them starts at a certain tile.
In addition, There are clients that move along a certain circular path (each client has his own path). Every client has a few packages that are scattered over the map.

The map, the initial location of the drones and the packages, and the path of each client along with his packages are given as parameters to the game.

The goal is to deliver each client his packages in the minimal number of steps.

In each step I can control all of the drones to move (right, left, up and down according to the map), pickup a package (if the drone carries less than two packages), deliver a package (if its client is in the same tile) and to wait.

I need to think about an heuristics for the game: given a state (the location of each drone, package and client) I need to come up with an heuristic that will return a number. The returning number is used in a search algorithm, and the goal is to minimize the number of actions to the goal.

I am having troubles to think about a good heuristics, even when there is only one drone (and in the game there are a few). I thought about the shortest distance to a package or a tile of a client (which is complicated, since the clients are moving) , but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: What properties do you need your heuristic to have?  Do you need it to be admissible, so you can use A*?  If so, can you think of *any* way at all to get an overestimate (even a really bad one)?  What's the best you've been able to come up with so far?

Comment: @D.W. The heuristics doesn't need to be admissible. I have no idea other than calculating some distances, but it's complicated since each drone can carry up to 2 packages, and since the clients are moving.

Comment: Your title is too general, please improve it.

Comment: This problem looks like a generalization of the TSP. You could get inspiration from heuristics for the latter. https://stemlounge.com/animated-algorithms-for-the-traveling-salesman-problem/

Answer (score 0):

You can pick any (not-necessarily-optimal) simple heuristic strategy for delivering packages, figure out how long it would take with that strategy, and use that as your heuristic.

For example, here is one idea, based on hub-and-spoke distribution.  Let $H$ be a position in the center of the area, which will represent the hub.  The idea is that each package will be assigned more or less arbitrarily to a drone, and that drone will fly from $H$ to pick up the package and then deliver it immediately and fly back to $H$ (so the drone only carries at much one package at a time).

For each package, compute the shortest time for a drone starting at $H$ to fly from $H$ to the package, then deliver from there to the client's future location, then fly from there back to $H$.  (You can compute this by looping over all future client locations, and computing the Manhattan distance between each pair of those points, and comparing to the time when the client will be at that future location.)

Now sum up all of these times, plus the time it takes for each drone to fly from its starting point to $H$.  Divide by the number of drones.  The result is an estimate of the
time it will take all packages (likely an over-estimate, as it uses a highly non-optimal strategy for distribution).

Of course, if this is too coarse an estimate, you can pick a slightly better strategy.  For instance, maybe you use a greedy heuristic: whenever a drone is free, it picks the package that it can deliver first, and takes responsibility for that package and immediately flies to it and delivers it.  You can use your creativity in coming up with simple strategies, and use the time they take as your heuristic.